# "Pages in a navbar initialize repeatedly" OR "Pages reinitialize on every navigation in a TabBar based App in Jquery Mobile"- Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following markup(in the first Tab)-

```
    <div data-role="navbar" class="myClass">
    <ul>
    <li><a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="Tab1.html"  data-transition="slidefade" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" id="favorite" data-icon="custom">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="Tab2.html" data-transition="slidefade" id="recent" data-icon="custom">Tab2</a></li> 
    <li><a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="Tab3.html" data-transition="slidefade" id="contacts" data-icon="custom">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="Tab4.html"  data-transition="slidefade" id="keypad" data-icon="custom">Tab4</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

When I toggle between the pages by taping the navbar(have made it look like an iOS native UITabBar via CSS), the corresponding .html file is initialized whenever I navigate to the Tab(I want the pages to initialize only once in the App life cycle).

When I remove the attributes `rel="external" data-ajax="false"` the problem is solved but only in Safari browser, Chrome stops navigating to the page and gives an error- "Error Loading Page". - 
**<----Is this a known behavior of  Chrome browser?**

Also, if I declare an object like- `window.variable=xyz;`  the value stored in `window.variable` is lost as soon as I navigate away from the page i.e. the Application is reinitializing  after every tap on the navbar and I am not able to share the `window` object in the entire App.

And, if I give-

```
<script>
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            alert('Page inited');                     
});
 </script>
```

in the Headers of Tab1.html, Tab2.html, Tab3.html and Tab4.html the script i.e. the entire header in the markup is called whenever i navigate to the corresponding Tab page which I would not like to happen.

**Is this a known issue/feature in Google Chrome Browser?** Safari- which is also built on Webkit behaves differently.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely remove **rel="external"** & **data-ajax="false"** atributes, they are preventing page cashing.

Then you need to turn cashing on like this:

```
$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
});
```

Use this option **ONLY** in case you want every page cashed. In the case you want to cash only certain pages use this analogy:

```
<div data-role="page" id="cacheMe" data-dom-cache="true">
```

You can also cache a page programmatically like this:

```
pageContainerElement.page({ domCache: true });
```

In case you have multiple pages in multiple html-s you will need to use data-prefetch attribute like this:

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

Here you will find my other answer about this kind of cashing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019929/1848600

Now something about persistent objects. In case you have followed top instructions you can simply create a persistent object like this:

var someObject = {
    option1 : '',
    option2 : 0,
    option3 : '' //etc..
}

**rel="external"** & **data-ajax="false"** will prevent object persistence in jQM case, those attributes act like page refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gajotres!
I tried both $.mobile.page.prototype.option.domCache = true and data-prefetch ways separately, all works fine in Safari but in Chrome, I have the same error coming-"Error loading Page"..  Chrome wouldn't even navigate until i put rel="external" & data-ajax="false" attributes in <a> tag.

Comment: and yes, if I put the mark-up of all the .html files in the same file under <div data-role="page">Page Mark up</div> and put href="#tabPageId" in <a> tag of the navbar all works fine in Safari and Chrome.